# Gradle Error Could not find com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0 with Eclipse exported project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, gradle, android-studio

I have been stuck on this for days/weeks. I am trying to include the aar for actionbarsherlock and I keep on getting this error:

```
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
    Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_DebugCompile'.
      Could not find com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0.
          Required by:
           :directory_name:unspecified
```

I've done this with a normal application started in Android Studio and it works fine. My Project is one that was exported from eclipse (with gradle of course). I feel as if it isn't looking through the maven repositories, and there has to be a setting that will fix this. Any Help will be appreciated!!

build.xml:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Notice 2 changes to the repositories section within buildscript, and the addition of repositories in the root.