# Android studio with actionbar sherlock, sliding menu and google play services

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, android-studio

I am trying to export our eclipse based project to android studio. Our project is pretty complex and have a long list of dependencies. I used the eclipse based [export](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) and import to android studio worked fairly ok.

Currently my build.gradle has these dependencies based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17243377/31252 and sample [build.gradle](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Gradle-Sample/blob/master/build.gradle) file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
```

But I still seeing compilation errors failing on actionbarsherlock.

```
error: cannot find symbol class SherlockMapFragment
error: package com.google.maps.android.ui does not exist
error: cannot find symbol class SherlockMapFragment
```

I tried various combinations including

1. Tried an older play services 3.2+, this failed with problem in android manifest
2. Tried apklib in place of aar for actionbar sherlock
3. Tried - [Gradle Error Could not find com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0 with Eclipse exported project in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867570/gradle-error-could-not-find-com-actionbarsherlockactionbarsherlock4-4-0-with-e)
4. Also tried importing actionbarsherlock.jar generated elsewhere as jar file.
5. Import ABS project as a maven dependency module - this messed up my project structure big time.

But the above problem is still persistent. I also have slidingmenu that is throwing compile errors but first I want to tackle actionbarsherlock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a customization in the ABS project, I moved SherlockMapFragment class to our project and adjusted namespaces and this seem to work now

Comment: You should mark your own answer accepted now (assuming it will let you mark it that way without needing to wait).